# Keyboard is not working after removing xf86-input-libinput and tty not working

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, plasma5, surface

**Problem:** Keyboard is not working after removing xf86-input-libinput - and now I cannot login in Plasma 5; when I try to type my password, nothing happens.

**Reason for removing xf86-input-libinput:**: I needed Wayland's synaps instead of xorg-server as the configuration of touchpad's sensitivity was grey. I read in forums I needed to remove xf86-input-libinput

**Code for removing:** I removed  xf86-input-libinput via

```
yay -Rdd xf86-input-libinput
```

**Which linux and which machine:** Arch Linux for Surface Pro 4

**What I tried to recover:**
*I tried to go to tty via:*

- <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> till <kbd>F2</kbd>
- <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> till <kbd>F2</kbd>
  *I tried recovery boot via*
- <kbd>SHFT</kbd>
- <kbd>del</kbd>
- <kbd>F1</kbd> till <kbd>F2</kbd>

*Result:* nothing happens - I still see the KDE Plasma loging

**Conclusion:** I still cannot login in KDE Plasma as keyboard is dead

What can I do?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What is `synaps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the live image you used for the installation, you can boot using that, chroot into your installation and reinstall whatever you uninstalled. In the future, refrain from using the -Rdd switch. There is an explicit warning against using this switch in the Arch wiki as it can break your system

Comment: Perfect advice. Now, I could login. Bw Roberto and thnx